# Filter out zeros in data frames using for loops in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a bunch of data frames in my global environment which each have 5 columns, and I want to filter out the rows in all of them that contain zeros in only the 4th and 5th columns.  I tried listing all the data frames and running a for loop using the following code:

```
all_frames <- list(aa,bb,cc,dd,ee,ff,gg,hh,ii,jj)

for (i in all_frames) {
  i <- i[apply(i[,-c(1:3)], 1, function(x) !all(x==0)),]
      
    }
```

Unfortunately this does not work, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Could you be a little more specific with *"contain zeros in only the 4th and 5th columns"*? Your code with `!all(x==0)` looks like "*filter out rows where both the 4th and 5th columns are 0"*, is that right?

Answer (score 1):

In base R you can `subset` using column names or column numbers.  E.g.:

```
subset(mtcars, cyl == 4 & mpg < 25)
subset(mtcars, mtcars[, 2] == 4 & mtcars[, 1] < 25)
```

Simply replace mtcars with your dataframe and conditions

To process a list of dataframes use `lapply`

```
newdfs <- lapply(all_frames, function(x) subset(x, x[, 4] != 0 & x[, 5] != 0))
```

Comment: Got it, thanks.  So I should've been more clear as @Gregor Thomas said, I want all the rows where columns 4 and 5 both contain zeros to go away.  The way you have it written subsets or keeps the rows where columns 4 and 5 are both zero.  I'm assuming I would put a "!" somewhere to specify not zero.  Where would that go?

Comment: No worries, interestingly that seemed to act more like an "or" statement where all the rows that had a zero in column 4 OR column 5 were removed.  In my data there are some rows that have a zero in column 4 and a non-zero number number in column 5 and I wanted to keep those rows, but those rows were removed as well.  But I got what I wanted by doing: subset(x, x[, 5] >0).  Thanks!